# Android Gradle Dependency

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to add the following dependency in my cordova project. However, the dependency is getting ignored during build.

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
```

From stackoverflow answers on similar questions, I realized I've to exclude few modules and groups.

So I made the following changes to dependencies.

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'){
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
}
```

However, I'm still getting this warning.

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it 
 may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
 In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages.
```

As a result of this, all my HTTP commands like HTTP Post, HTTP Client etc are not resolved.

Can someone suggest me what exactly has to be excluded and if any configuration changes are required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTTP library by adding this line to build script of your app:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    // other lines
}
```

Hope this help **:)**

Comment: Make sure you're doing it in the right build.gradle file. I had this issue with the Google LVL but kept putting it in the app's build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Use repacked version of the Apache http client suitable for respective android version.

For Android API 22 and older

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

For Android API 23 and newer

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}
```

This link has more info - https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Comment: I had +1'd this too soon. I get errors:
cannot find symbol class NameValuePair
cannot find symbol variable URLEncodedUtils
cannot find symbol class NameValuePair
Even with the new dependencies

Comment: @Oded I guess you are still missing some dependencies.

Comment: I think I may have put the dependencies in the wrong build.gradle file.